# Template function in define

Tags: c++, templates, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some template function and I want to call it using define in C++:

```
#define CONFIG(key, type, def) getValue<type>(key, def);
```

Of course, it won't work. Could I make something like this?

Comment: The real question, of course, is why use a macro... ? Also, you'll be in trouble if any of your parameter needs a comma :x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine:

```
template<typename T>
T getValue( int, int ) { return T(); }

#define CONFIG(key, type, def) getValue<type>(key, def);


int main()
{
    CONFIG(1, int, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And could I use default values in defines? Like: #define CONFIG(key, type, def="") ...?

Comment: No -- in that case, you'd want to define the default in the template itself, assuming you have control of the code.

Comment: And if not, write another template with the default in place, and have your macro reference that.